# F-division and T-division

Tags: math

I thought I understood the division  concept but it seems I don't. The example explains T and F division of `42/-10` and `-42/10`. And my task is as follows:

You F-divided some positive number by `−5` and obtained a remainder of `1` What remainder will you obtain T-dividing this number by `−5`?

[image]
:

Normally I wouldn't hesitate with division but I failed to understand this concept.

Comment: Can you give some context?  Where is this from?  (These are not widely-known names, even if the concept might be.)  And why the language tags?

Answer (score -1):

`trunc(n)` will always round towards zero.

`floor(n)` will always round down.

If `n` is positive, they will behave identically. (`trunc(4.7) = 4` and `floor(4.7) = 4`)

But if `n` is negative, they will round in opposite directions. (`trunc(-4.7) = -4` and `floor(-4.7) = -5`)

Then we just expand this so that `n` is the result of division. For T division, we divide and then round towards zero. For F division, we divide and then round down.